# Chamar imagem de perfil dos amigos com API GRAPH

Tags: javascript, facebook

Como faço para chamar a imagem de perfil dos meu amigos?

A minha eu já consigo buscar desta forma `me/picture?redirect=false`.

Comment: Oi, Jefferson, o correto é colocar a Tag da linguagem relevante. E também o trecho de código que usa para buscar sua imagem.

Comment: então, eu uso esse código aqui para chamar a minha foto " FB.api('me/picture', function(info_pic) {
  var foto=info_pic.data.url;
  console.log(info_pic);
  $("#foto1").html("<img width=30 height=30 src=" + foto + ">");
  });  " gostaria de saber como faço pra chamar dos meus amigos aleatóriamente

Comment: Clique em [edit] abaixo da pergunta para incluir novas informações e formatar o código direitinho.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente o comando é

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (StatusAutorizacao())
    {
        Facebook.FacebookClient client = new Facebook.FacebookClient(access_token);
        client.AppId = App_Id;
        client.AppSecret = App_Secret;
        dynamic friends = client.Get("me/friends/?fields=name,birthday,picture, gender");
        IEnumerable  listafriends = (from c in ((IEnumerable)friends.data)
                                select new
                                {
                                    Id = c.id, 
                                    Name = c.name,
                                    Birthday = c.birthday,
                                    Picture = c.picture.data.url,
                                    Sexo = c.gender
                                }).AsEnumerable();
        return View(listafriends);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

E no index, você coloca a view

```
@model IEnumerable  
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}                            
Index
@foreach (object item in Model)
{
    Type type = item.GetType();   
    
        
        @String.Format("{0} {1}",
            type.GetProperty("Id").GetValue(item,null).ToString(),
            type.GetProperty("Name").GetValue(item,null).ToString())
    
}
```

Comment: Desculpa acho que esqueci de especificar que estou utilizando javascript ;(